# Random process involving CDF and PDF of standard normal.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Im studying old exams and found this one:

Let 
$ \Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1} { \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-y^2 /2} dy $
and $ \phi(x)=\Phi^\prime(x)=\frac{1} { \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-x^2 /2} $
be the standard normal (zero - mean and unit variance) cummulative probability distribution function and the standard normal probability density function, respectively. Find a random process $(X(t), \, t \in \mathbb{R}) $ such that the following calculation is valid:
\begin{align}P\left(X(1) ≤ 0, X(2) ≤ 0\right) &= P\left(X(1) ≤ 0, X(2)-\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}X(1)≤-\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}X(1)\right)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{0} P\left(X(2)-\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}X(1)≤-\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}x\right)\phi(x) dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \Phi(-x)\phi(x) dx =\int_{0}^{\infty} \Phi(x)\phi(x) dx =\Bigg[\frac{\Phi(x)^2} {2}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{0}=\frac{3} {8}\end{align}

How should I be thinking about solving a task like this?

Comment: One requires that $X_1$ and $\sqrt2X_2-X_1$ are i.i.d. standard normal. One way to achieve this is to define, for every $t$, $$X_t=\cos(\pi t/4)U+\sin(\pi t/4)V,$$ for some fixed $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard normal.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But i have to admit i am totally lost here. The solution the professor is giving is the following:
A zero-mean unit-variance Gaussian process with $$E(X(1)X(2)) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$$
, because for such a process $X(1)$ and $X(2)− (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}) X(1)$ are independent $(a)$
and $$P(X(2)−(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}) X(1) ≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} x) = \Phi(−x) (b)$$ 
since $X(2)− (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}) X(1)$ is a Gaussian random variable with variance $(\frac{1}{{2}})(c)$ 
If anyone could explain the _lines_ (a), (b) and (c) from the basics i would really appreciate it.

Comment: How is this solution providing a process $(X_t)$ indexed by $t$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I have no idea. But i double checked and at least i have not misquoted him.